# How to ground old style Romex (no ground) multi-wire circult

Tags: electrical-distribution

I have a multi-wire that is very old and doesn't have a ground.  I'd like to change this to using new Romex so that AFCI breakers will work.  My question is this... Can I band the red wire in my multiwire cable with green tape and then use that as a ground?  Of course, I'd band it with tape on both ends....

The alternative is to either abandon the red wire and use a ground from another source in the next junction box (available) or replace the old 12-3 Romex that doesn't have a ground with a new 12-2 also.

Phrased differently:
1. Replace 12-3 w/o ground with two 12-2 that have grounds
2. Replace 12-3 w/o ground with one 12-2 with ground and reuse old 12-3 w/o ground, using ground from new 12-2 in the next junction box
3.  Replace 12-3 w/o ground with one 12-2 with ground and reuse old 12-3 w/o ground, banding with green tape the red wire and using that as the 12-3's ground.

Thanks!

Comment: Is 12/3 with ground not an option?

Comment: I agree with @mjohns. Installing new 12/3  w/ ground, and a double pole CAFCI breaker is also an option (and possibly the *best* option)..

Comment: Well, I guess the observation I would have there is... If I have to pull another Romex then why pull a 12-3.  I can pull two 12-2.  Plus, I'm not 100% sure California (CEC) will allow multiwire now.  I have to check.  But, again, if I have to pull something then option #3 would be most acceptable.  In that, I would pull a single 12-2 and either abandon the red wire in the old 12-3 or tape it and use it as a ground.

Comment: Oh, I also may not have been very clear...  The 12-3 I have now does *NOT* have a ground wire.  It is from the late 50's.  There are 3 wires total in it: red, black, and white.  There is no bare copper ground as you have in modern 12-3

Comment: OK... I did more digging.  I thought multiwire had been disallowed but I was wrong.  I have a ground at the far end already so I can use that (believe that is legal).  IF I legally can use a 220V AFCI in a multiwire scenario then that seems like it is the best way to go.